# unknown field in struct literal

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a struct, and it is giving me an error, telling me the field is unknown.

The struct I am trying to initialize is:

```
package yelk

type PhoneOptions struct {
    phone string
    cc    string
    lang  string
}
```

And I'm trying to initialize a `PhoneOptions` struct in `cli.go` like this:

```
number := os.Args[1]
phoneOptions := yelk.PhoneOptions{phone: number}
```

I do `go run cli.go 5555555555` but it gives me an error

```
./cli.go:29: unknown yelk.PhoneOptions field 'phone' in struct literal
```

All The StackOverflow posts I've seen with this error seem to be from nested structs. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong. `cli.go` will give this error if I just try to run `go build` on it, so I don't think it's the inputs I've been running it with.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Fields that start with lower case characters are package internal and not exposed, If you want to reference the field from another package it needs to start with an upper case character, eg.

```
package yelk

type PhoneOptions struct {
    Phone string
    Cc    string
    Lang  string
}
```

and then

```
number := os.Args[1]
phoneOptions := yelk.PhoneOptions{Phone: number}
```

Comment: Thanks!  The error wording confused me so I forgot all about visibility rules...  Filed https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31053 to improve the error message.